# How to join data from two views in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have two views view1 and view2 I want to join the data from both views. The data example is the following : view1

| old_NUmbers | counts |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 |
| 324 | 3 |
| 4454 | 13 |
| 343433 | 20 |

View2 data:

| numbers | counts |
| --- | --- |
| 343344 | 10 |
| 24344 | 15 |

So the desired result which I want is the following:

| old_NUmbers | counts | numbers | counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 | 343344 | 10 |
| 324 | 3 | 24344 | 15 |
| 4454 | 13 |  |  |
| 343433 | 20 |  |  |

Comment: You seem to be combining more than joining, as there are no common columns/values. So what is the logic - give every row in each view a nominal value (e.g. via row_number() - perhaps ordered by some crieteria) and then full outer join those on that value? If so which part are you stuck on? Or do the underlying tables behind the views have common data you could use to join - in which case using the views might not be the best option? Please edit your question to explain the logic though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're combining the results and want to align data from the two views in `counts` order, you can generate a nominal ordinal value for each row in each view, for example with the `row_number()` function:

```
select v.old_numbers, v.counts,
  row_number() over (order by v.counts, v.old_numbers)
from view1 v
```

and something similar for the other view; then use those as inline views or CTEs, and perform a full outer join based on that ordinal value:

```
with v1 (old_numbers, counts, rn) as (
  select v.old_numbers, v.counts,
    row_number() over (order by v.counts, v.old_numbers)
  from view1 v
),
v2 (numbers, counts, rn) as (
  select v.numbers, v.counts,
    row_number() over (order by v.counts, v.numbers)
  from view2 v
)
select v1.old_numbers, v1.counts, v2.numbers, v2.counts
from v1
full outer join v2 on v2.rn = v1.rn
order by coalesce(v1.rn, v2.rn)
```

| OLD_NUMBERS | COUNTS | NUMBERS | COUNTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 | 343344 | 10 |
| 324 | 3 | 24344 | 15 |
| 4454 | 13 | *null* | *null* |
| 343433 | 20 | *null* | *null* |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f571e0f34673b2b4183671044c8620cb)